# Determine if there is a path between all vertex pairs on an directed graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, undirected-graph

#### Question

I have a question about this problem:

Given an directed graph that contains N vertices and M edges, please determine that "there is a path from vertex i to vertex j for all `1 <= i, j <= N`".

I want to solve for `N <= 500, M <= 250000`. 
I found the naive pathfinding algorithm with dfs but the time complexity is `O(N^2 M)`, so it is very slow. 
Please tell me the efficient algorithm to solve it.

#### Example

For example, if this graph is given:

[image: Example Graph]

The answer is NO because there isn't a path from 4 to 1.

Comment: @MitchWheat Edited a little.

Comment: @A.S.H Oh... I mistyped.

Comment: You can apply  [Kosaraju's algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components). After that, check if you have only one strongly-connected component. The algorithm has linear time complexity; O(M+N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm can me implemented with `O(N+M)` complexity.

1. Take any vertex `u`. Use [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm to reach other vertices. If any vertex is not reachable, return `NOK`.
2. Now do the same, but go to the opposite direction. If any vertex is not reachable, return `NOK`.
3. Return `OK`. (Here we know that there is a path from any vertex `v` to `u` because of [2], and there is a path from `u` to any vertex `w` because of [1].)